# Tortoise SVN undo checkout in repository

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am very new to Tortoise SVN so I hope I use the correct terminology...

I have a repository, say `C:/RCode` and I was checking it out into say `C:/Working`. I do not know what exactly went wrong, but I must have checked out something in my repository `C:/RCode`. As a result, this folder has now features of both a repository and a checked out folder - e.g. it now also has the green v icon overlay next to the icon overlay of a repository.

How can I tell Tortoise that this is should not be a checkout folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make Tortoise SVN forget a folder is a checked out folder, it suffices to show hidden files and folders in the folder of interest and then delete the hidden folder `.svn`

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is an [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html). An `svn checkout` is the process of tracking local changes into a series of deltas (inside that .svn folder) so that you may commit changes back to the repository.

An **export** does essentially what a checkout does, but without the version control aspect of it. The command you would run for your example would be:

```
svn export file:///C:/RCode C:/Working
```

Or if you're using TortoiseSVN:

1. Right click anywhere in Windows Explorer
2. Enter the URL of the repository and output directory
3. Specify a revision (HEAD by default)
4. Select OK.

Simply deleting the .svn folder works as well, but it's an extra step (along with cleaning your Recycle Bin). It's also worth noting that `svn export` is useful for making a copy of your local working copy (a checkout) to a non-versioned copy somewhere else on your local machine.

```
svn export C:/Working C:/NonCheckout
```